# What kind of technique is used right here?

Tags: javascript

I want to start, to dive more into web development. I used to be satisfied with an application that is simply working but now I want to focus a little bit on the ease of use and the design as well. I found a really cool website with a nice way to login. You do a javascript onclick (I guess) and then a little window pops up. I tried to figure out what it is and searched in the source code of [this site](http://www.aiga.org/) and I found following line where I still don't get how to do that.

```
<input
    type="image" name="ctl00$Header1$LoginUserControl1$BtnLogin" id="ctl00_Header1_LoginUserControl1_BtnLogin"
    title="Login"
    src="/media/images/login_button.png"
    onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$Header1$LoginUserControl1$BtnLogin&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;https://my.aiga.org/vango/core/login.aspx&quot;, false, false))" />
```

Does anyone have a guess how they designed that ?

**Edit**: I thank you very much for your answers. I really don't want to dive in into asp.net :/ Do you have any tutorials or suggestions on how to do that with javascript in some way ?

Comment: You can learn JQuery which is a library of code that makes life easier for programming in Javascript. In any case, you will need to learn some form of server side coding if you want to learn how to do things with information that comes from a page. Possible server side coding include: .NET webforms  / Java servlets / PHP

Comment: Here is a small pure javascript method to open such a window: http://jsfiddle.net/kumarmuthaliar/GG9Sa/1/

Comment: That is pretty awesome :D Why don't post that as an answer ? I try to learn node and express at the moment what should to the trick for the server side coding. And now it seems like I need to learn some JQuery

Comment: It isn't really the answer because you asked 'how it was designed', so I answered that. But anyway NodeJS is also a server side codign technology and will do you fine. good luck !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is auto generated by visual studio when an input control is dragged on the screen.
Visual studio adds a lot of code behind the scenes to make programing easier.

Here it adds JS code that when the button is clicked it performs what is called a post back.

It posts (just like a web form posts) and passes many parameters that show the state of the page, back to the server side code which handles it and generates a new answer page based on the current page's parameters.

Comment: Just to clarify, regarding the 'window' that pops up, it is just a div that is displayed on the rest of the html in a specific position. there are no real windows on a single html page. There are js libraries that make it easy to use such 'windows' instead of writing them from scratch

Answer (score 1):

It's probably an asp.net application/website.
If you want to know more about WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions
check msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163736.aspx
Hope that's help.